# Hierarchical numbering of flat XML with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, numbers, hierarchical, flat

I have a flat XML document that I want to number hierarchically. Is that even possible - with `<xsl:number ... count=''>`?

**XML-Source (part of it & simplified)**

```
<modul>
  <p>
  <h1>A Heading
  <p>
  <figure>
    <img>
  <h2>A Heading
  <p>
  <h1>A Heading
  <p>
  <h2>A Heading
  <p>
  <h3>A Heading
  <p>
<modul>
```

**Desired output (html)**

```
<html>
      <p>
      <h1>1. A Heading
      <p>
      <figure>
        <img>
      <h2>1.2 A Heading
      <p>
      <h1>2. A Heading
      <p>
      <h2>2.1 A Heading
      <p>
      <h3>2.1.1 A Heading
      <p>
</html>
```

**Stylesheet (part)**

```
  <xsl:template match="h1">
            <h1>
            <xsl:number count="h1"/>
                <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </h1>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="h2">
            <h2>
                <xsl:number count="h1 | h2" level="multiple" format="1.1.1."/>  
                <xsl:apply-templates/>  
            </h2>
     </xsl:template>
```

I´m able to number all h1 and h2 elements, but all I get is a continuous numbering (all h-element are continuous numbered). I can´t figure out, how to get h2/h3 elements in the next level. Is hierarchical numbering here at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this with level="multiple".

I think you can get the required number for (say) an h3 element using

```
<xsl:template match="h3" mode="number">
  <xsl:number level="any" count="h1"/>
  <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
  <xsl:number level="any" count="h2" from="h1"/>
  <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
  <xsl:number level="any" count="h3" from="h2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and you can then define similar template rules for other levels, and get the level number for a section using `<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="number"/>`.

A couple of caveats: (a) I haven't tested this, and (b) the rules for `xsl:number` in XSLT 1.0 leave some cases under-specified, and different XSLT 1.0 implementations are known to have interpreted the rules in different ways. The rules in XSLT 2.0 are much more precise, and in some edge cases give results that differ from (some readings of) the 1.0 specification.

It's possible that relying on CSS for numbering might provide an alternative solution.

Another approach would be to use positional grouping to convert the flat structure into an HTML5 nested section structure, in which case level="multiple" solves the numbering problem.

Comment: This works. With a few minor adjustments, I was able to incorporate it into my stylesheet. The other way, to convert the flat XML into a hierarchical structure, is also an option, but I put it at the end of the list. By the way, I ordered your "Programmers Reference" a few days ago and now I'm waiting for it to arrive :). Nice to make your "acquaintance" here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="modul">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="figure">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="img">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="h1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:number count="h1" level="any" format="1"/>
            <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:number count="h1" level="any" format="1"/>
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:number from="h1" count="h2" level="any"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h3">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:number count="h1" level="any" format="1"/>
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:number from="h1" count="h2" level="any"/>
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:number from="h2" count="h3" level="any"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Try this

Comment: As far as I can see, this is the same solution as answer above.